# Parsing and structuring of a text file

Tags: ruby, parsing

I need help and I use Ruby. I had a text file with next contain:

```
Head 1
a 10
b 14
c 15
d 16
e 17
f 88
Head 4
r 32
t 55
s 79
r 22
t 88
y 53
o 78
p 90
m 44
Head 53
y 22
b 33
Head 33
z 11
d 66
v 88
b 69
Head 32
n 88
m 89
b 88
```

And I want parse and structure this file to next plane. I want to get next data:

```
Head 1, f 88
Head 4, t 88
Head 33, v 88
Head 32, n 88
Head 32, b 88
```

Please tell me how how can I make such code on a ruby?

I think first I have its put all the lines in the array:

```
lines = Array.new
File.open('C:/file/file.txt', 'r').each { |line| lines << line }
```

but what should I do next?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to grab everything having `88` value? It is unclear from the question. Also, please show us what have you tried already.

Comment: @il_raffa Thanks for edit

Comment: @Mudasobwa Yes, I want to select all records with 88 and their headers

Comment: `lines = Array.new
File.open('C:/file/file.txt', 'r').each { |line| lines << line }                                p lines.grep (/88/)`                                                                                                         I do not know how to connect the appropriate headers with 88

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the answer to @mudasobwa question "Do you want to grab everything having 88 value?" this is the solution

```
lines = File.open("file.txt").to_a
lines.map!(&:chomp) # remove line breaks

current_head = ""
res = []

lines.each do |line|
  case line
  when /Head \d+/
    current_head = line
  when /\w{1} 88/
    res << "#{current_head}, #{line}"
  end
end

puts res
```

Comment: This is the best approach, imo. I have a few suggestions. 1. Use `File.foreach('file.txt').with_object([]) do |line, res|` in place of all the lines through `lines.each do |line|`. `with_object([])` initializes `res` and causes the block return `res`. 2. No need to initialize `current_head`. 3. `\w{1}` is the same as `\w`, but you may want to be more specific, such as using `[[:lower:]]` or `[[:lower:]]+`. 4. After `when /Head \d+/` perhaps write `head=line; when /[[:lower:]]+\s+88/; res << "#{head.chomp}, #{line.chomp}"; end`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you are right, I have written a beginner level solution, but yes you have the pro solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have written your data to the file 'temp':

First define a regular expression for extracting the lines of the file that are of interest.

```
r = /
    Head\s+\d+        # match 'Head', > 0 spaces, ?= 1 digits in capture group 1
    |                 # or
    [[:lower:]]+\s+88 # match > 0 lower case letters, > 0 spaces, '88'
    /xm               # free-spacing regex definition and multi-line modes
```

Now perform the following operations on the file.

```
File.read('temp').scan(r).
                  slice_before { |line| line.start_with?('Head ') }.
                  reject { |a| a.size == 1 }.
                  flat_map { |head, *rest| [head].product(rest) }.
                  map { |a| "%s, %s" % a }
  #=> ["Head 1, f 88", "Head 4, t 88", "Head 33, v 88",
  #    "Head 32, n 88", "Head 32, b 88"]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = File.read('temp').scan(r)
  #=> ["Head 1", "f 88", "Head 4", "t 88", "Head 53", "Head 33",
  #    "v 88", "Head 32", "n 88", "b 88"]
b = a.slice_before { |line| line.start_with?('Head') }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007ffd218387b0>:each>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by the enumerator `b` by converting it to an array.

```
b.to_a
  #=> [["Head 1", "f 88"], ["Head 4", "t 88"], ["Head 53"],
  #    ["Head 33", "v 88"], ["Head 32", "n 88", "b 88"]]
```

Now remove all arrays of size 1 from `b`.

```
c = b.reject { |a| a.size == 1 }
  #=> [["Head 1", "f 88"], ["Head 4", "t 88"], ["Head 33", "v 88"],
  # ["Head 32", "n 88", "b 88"]]
```

Next we use [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-product) to associate each "Head" with all the lines following (before the next "Head" or the end of the file) that end `88\n`.

```
d = c.flat_map { |head, *rest| [head].product(rest) }
  #=> [["Head 1", "f 88"], ["Head 4", "t 88"], ["Head 33", "v 88"],
  #    ["Head 32", "n 88"], ["Head 32", "b 88"]]
```

Lastly, convert each element of `d` to a string.

```
d.map { |a| "%s, %s" % a }
  #=> ["Head 1, f 88", "Head 4, t 88", "Head 33, v 88",
  #    "Head 32, n 88", "Head 32, b 88"]
```