# Multi-level parsing text

Tags: ruby, parsing, case-when

The last time I had a problem:
[Parsing and structuring of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40604745/parsing-and-structuring-of-a-text-file)
Now I imagine complicated conditions.
For example. I had a text file with next contain:

```
Head 1
Subhead 1
a 10
b 14
c 88
Subhead 2
a 15
b 16
c 17
d 88
Subhead 3
a 55
b 36
c 87
Head 4
Subhead 1
r 32
t 55
s 79
r 22
t 88
y 53
o 78
p 90
m 44
Head 53
Subtitle 1
y 22
b 33
Subtitle 2
a 88
g 43
r 87
Head 33
Subhead 1 
z 11
d 66
v 88
b 69
Head 32
Subhead 1
n 88
m 89
b 88
Subhead 2
b 88
m 43
```

Now I need structure text to next plane. I want to get next data:

```
Head 1, Subhead 1, c 88
Head 1, Subhead 2, d 88
Head 4, Subhead 1, t 88
Head 53, Subhead 2, a 88
Head 33, Subhead 1, v 88
Head 32, Subhead 1, n 88
Head 32, Subhead 1, b 88
Head 32, Subhead 2, b 88
```

That is, I want to get all the rows with 88 indicating the head and subhead.

My actions:

```
lines = File.open("file.txt").to_a
lines.map!(&:chomp) # remove line breaks

current_head = ""
res = []

lines.each do |line|
  case line
  when /Head \d+/
    current_head = line
  when /Subhead/
    sub = line
  when /\w{1} 88/
  num = line
    res << "#{current_head}, #{sub}, #{num}"
  end
end

puts res
```

When I use this method I get a string without NUM values.

Whether to perform my task means "case when" possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables declared inside the `each` block do not persist between iterations. When the iteration ends, those variables disappear, which is why you're losing the previous `sub` value. To fix it, move the `sub` variable to the outer scope by initializing it before the `each`, just like you have with `current_head`:

```
current_head = ""
current_sub = ""
res = []

lines.each do |line|
  case line
  when /Head \d+/
    current_head = line
  when /Subhead/
    current_sub = line
  when /\w{1} 88/
  num = line
    res << "#{current_head}, #{current_sub}, #{num}"
  end
end
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/GBKn

Comment: Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep variables between two iterations, you could use instance variables.

`File.foreach` is the recommended way of reading a file :

```
res = []
File.foreach("file.txt") do |line|
  line.chomp!
  case line
  when /Head \d+/
    @current_head = line
  when /Sub(head|title)/
    @sub = line
  when /\w 88/
    num = line
    res << "#{@current_head}, #{@sub}, #{num}"
  end
end
puts res
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! foreach is really convenient