# Insert into mysql database data of parsing text file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, case-when, tiny-tds

In this question [Multi-level parsing text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513224/multi-level-parsing-text) I asked how can I parse a file into a text file.
I further complicated the conditions and decided to write the data to the mysql database.
The original data is the same.

I had a text file with next contain:

```
Head 1
Subhead 1
a 10
b 14
c 88
Subhead 2
a 15
b 16
c 17
d 88
Subhead 3
a 55
b 36
c 87
Head 4
Subhead 1
r 32
t 55
s 79
r 22
t 88
y 53
o 78
p 90
m 44
Head 53
Subtitle 1
y 22
b 33
Subtitle 2
a 88
g 43
r 87
Head 33
Subhead 1 
z 11
d 66
v 88
b 69
Head 32
Subhead 1
n 88
m 89
b 88
Subhead 2
b 88
m 43
```

Now I need structure this text to next plane. I want to write this data to the mysql database.
My actions:

```
require 'tiny_tds'
current_head = ""
current_sub = ""
res = []

    @host  = 'server'
    @user  = 'user'
    @pass  = 'pass'

lines.each do |line|
  case line
  when /Head \d+/
    current_head = line
  when /Subhead/
    current_sub = line
  when /\w{1} 88/
  num = line
    res << "#{current_head}, #{current_sub}, #{num}"

    conn = TinyTds::Client.new(:host => @host, :username => @user, :password => @pass)
    insert_string = "insert into table (head, sub, num) VALUES (#{res})"
    conn.execute(insert_string)

  end
end
```

As a result, I can insert only one line into the database. In addition, the process of insertion is very slow, how can I speed up the process?

I need this result into database:

```
head   | Sub      | num  |
_________________________
Head 1 | Subhead 1| c 88 |
Head 1 | Subhead 2| d 88 |
Head 4 | Subhead 1| t 88 |
Head 53| Subhead 2| a 88 |
Head 33| Subhead 1| v 88 |
Head 32| Subhead 1| n 88 |
Head 32| Subhead 1| b 88 |
Head 32| Subhead 2| b 88 |
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, my version works, but I did not take into account the types of data in the database. If someone knows how to make my algorithm faster, then tell me

Comment: maybe setup connection outside the each-loop?